# In Python, is there a way to create headers from values in a string?

Tags: python, nltk

I am working in Python and I am a bit stumped on this one. I have txt files which I am trying to do NLP analysis on. Each file is in their own respective folders so it would be great if I could do this for every text file which is formatted the same. I have the title and the date in the same string as the body text. Each document has a different title and year. Ultimately it would be great to have all of the documents under one data frame with the below headers.

**Example:**

<title="Special Session Message to Congress">

<date="May 16, 1797">
The personal inconveniences...

**I would like it to be like the following (3 column headers: Title, Year, Body):**

Title | Year | Body

Special Session Message | 1797 | The personal inconveniences...

I am assuming I would need a loop to perform the operation on all documents in a folder. How would I go about doing that? Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Is your question "How do I process all of the files in a directory?", or "How do I extract values from an HTML-like tag such as `<title="Hello">`"?

Comment: It is both. Extracting the values from each file in the directory and not having to type each filename out individually.